# How to change zIndex of an element on click in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, z-index

I want to change z-Index on button click. I have a static image and a dynamic div. Now I want to send the #imgDiv1 behind the static image. But I don't know how to do this. I tried everything but all in vain.

Here is the live demo. [jholo.com](http://www.jholo.com/Customize.php5?desID=2) I want to implement this concept in this web application.

Here is my mark up

```
<div id="safeZone">
    <img src="default.png" />

    <div id="imgDiv1">
         <img src="myPic.jpg" />
    </div>

</div>

<input id="back" type="button" value="Send To Back"/>
<input id="front" type="button" value="Bring To Front"/>
```

jQuery

```
 $(document).ready(function(){ 

   $("#back").click(function(){
      $("#imgDiv1").css("z-index","-10");
   });

   $("#front").click(function(){
      $("#imgDiv1").css("z-index","10");
   });

});
```

[image: This is what i want]

Comment: Do you have other CSS that goes with this that sets the `position` property?  `z-index` has no effect on objects with the `position` property set to something like `absolute` or `fixed`.

Comment: no. I dont have other css. :(

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using? Seems to work in this example: http://jsfiddle.net/g9XbD/ Note the css that sets `position: absolute`.

Comment: 1.10.2. I don't understand whats wrong with this.

Comment: You must set position, as explained in answer bellow - something like this> http://jsfiddle.net/DDLp2/1/

Answer (score 5):

The `z-index` style property only takes affect on elements that are not `position: static`.  So, you will need to set the `position` property before you can see the impact of `z-index`.

HTML:

```
<button id="up">Up</button><button id="down">Down</button>
<div id="container">
    <img id="img1" src="http://dummyimage.com/300x200/ff0000/fff.jpg">
    <img src="http://dummyimage.com/300x200/00ff00/fff.jpg">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#container img {position: absolute;}
#container {height: 200px; width: 300px;}
```

Code:

```
$("#up").click(function(){
     $("#img1").css("z-index", -10);
  });

$("#down").click(function(){
    $("#img1").css("z-index",10);
});
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/5Efm3/

---

Edit - Responding to your additional edit:

To achieve the effect you're looking for, you will also need the snowflake like image to have transparency inside the snowflake shape thus allowing the behind image to show through which means it can't be a JPG,. It could be GIF or PNG.

Comment: @FazilMir - I added comments to my answer about the new requirement you added to your question.  You will need an image with transparency.

Comment: bro the problem is I am developing customizable printing web application. A User can upload any kind of image png, gif, jpg. So what I want if the user upload some design in png, he should be able to send or bring the image forward or backward..

Everything is adding dynamically, and if i use position absolute then i wont be able to use automatic height which is really important.

Comment: @FazilMir - I gave you the facts.  You can't use `z-index` unless the element is positioned.  Not sure what else you want me to say.

Comment: moment bro. I will upload my website with demo. So that i can show you what i want.

Comment: @FazilMir - So, what part of this http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/a9brN/ that uses your own transparent image doesn't work?  I'm not understanding what you want help with.

Comment: i tried to do so but it not working properly in the web application :( when I change position to absolute, the functionality doesn't work properly then.

Comment: @FazilMir - then you need to ask a more specific layout question.  It is very common to use `position: absolute` inside some containers which are `postion: relative` and that contains the children to within their borders and then the parent follows normal CSS layout.  The clean way to overlap two objects like you're asking for is with `position: absolute`.  You can see in my demo how the container is `position: relative` to contain the children.

Comment: please check this now. Here is the jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/FazilMir/5Efm3/14/ . My container is also absolute. So when i send image to back, it goes behind the container. Check the fiddle.

Comment: @FazilMir - If you set the z-index to be less than 0, then it will go behind the container unless you set the z-index of the container even smaller.  You can fix, by either setting the z-index of the behind object to `+1` instead of `-10` or set z-index of container to `-20`.  Also, your container is not `position: absolute` in the jsFiddle because it is set to `position: relative` (as it probably should be) after the CSS line you added.  See http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/5Efm3/17/ for a fix to the z-index values.

Answer (score 0):

I used opacity instead of z-index... is that helpful?

```
$("#down").click(function(){
 $("#img1").css("opacity", 0.0);
$("#img2").css("opacity", 1.0);
  });

$("#up").click(function(){
$("#img2").css("opacity",0.0);
$("#img1").css("opacity", 1.0);
});
```

the js fiddle link is.. http://jsfiddle.net/6rwBR/   hopefully this helps

Comment: actually i dont want opacity. Both the images should remain visible.